# Convert EWS StoreId (FolderID) to Graph API restId using translateExchangeIds?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there any possible way to convert `Get-MailboxFolderStatistics` returned `folderId` (`storeId`) to Microsoft Graph API `restId`?

I've tried to use `users/{userId}/translateExchangeIds` endpoint but didn't get any useful results.

[image]

Does `users/{userId}/translateExchangeIds` endpoint support translating `storeId` to `restId`?

Is there any other way to translate this id's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `storeId` to `entryId` by yourself and then use `users/{userId}/translateExchangeIds` to convert `entryId` to `restId`.

For converting `storeId` to `entryId` convert `folderId` from base64 string to hex string. Then parse `entryId` hex string and encode `entryId` hex string to `entryId`.

```
$folderId = "LgAAAADMaqNx7y87SYAkFzRBDsNkAQDBGxV/99wUQoEROcv7tgfjAAAWrAyWAAAB"

# convert from base64 to bytes
$folderIdBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($folderId)

# convert byte array to string, remove '-' and ignore first byte
$folderIdHexString = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($folderIdBytes).Replace('-','')
$folderIdHexStringLength = $folderIdHexString.Length

# get hex entry id string by removing first and last byte
$entryIdHexString = $folderIdHexString.SubString(2,($folderIdHexStringLength-4))

# convert to byte array - two chars represents one byte
$entryIdBytes = [byte[]]::new($entryIdHexString.Length / 2)

For($i=0; $i -lt $entryIdHexString.Length; $i+=2){
    $entryIdTwoChars = $entryIdHexString.Substring($i, 2)
    $entryIdBytes[$i/2] = [convert]::ToByte($entryIdTwoChars, 16)
}

# convert bytes to base64 string
$entryIdBase64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($entryIdBytes)

# count how many '=' contains base64 entry id
$equalCharCount = $entryIdBase64.Length - $entryIdBase64.Replace('=','').Length

# trim '=', replace '/' with '-', replace '+' with '_' and add number of '=' at the end
$entryId = $entryIdBase64.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/','_').Replace('+','-')+$equalCharCount
```

`folderId` with value `LgAAAADMaqNx7y87SYAkFzRBDsNkAQDBGxV/99wUQoEROcv7tgfjAAAWrAyWAAAB` is converted to `entryId` `AAAAAMxqo3HvLztJgCQXNEEOw2QBAMEbFX_33BRCgRE5y_u2B-MAABasDJYAAA2`

Then use the converted `entryId` in the call

```
{
  "inputIds" : [
    "AAAAAMxqo3HvLztJgCQXNEEOw2QBAMEbFX_33BRCgRE5y_u2B-MAABasDJYAAA2"
  ],
  "sourceIdType": "entryId",
  "targetIdType": "restId"
}
```

Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.convertIdResult)",
    "value": [
        {
            "sourceId": "AAAAAMxqo3HvLztJgCQXNEEOw2QBAMEbFX_33BRCgRE5y_u2B-MAABasDJYAAA2",
            "targetId": "AAMkAGRkZTFiMDQxLWYzNDgtNGQ3ZS05Y2U3LWU1NWJhMTM5YTgwMAAuAAAAAADMaqNx7y87SYAkFzRBDsNkAQDBGxV-99wUQoEROcv7tgfjAAAWrAyWAAA="
        }
    ]
}
```

Resources:

[URL-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-translateexchangeids?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#exchangeidformat-values)

Comment: Thanks mate, It work in case of entryId. with ref. to these https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2744/converting-item-and-folder-ids-via-the-graph-api , Get-mailboxfolderstatistics returns id called StoreId (looks like these - LgAAAADMaqNx7y87SYAkFzRBDsNkAQDBGxV/99wUQoEROcv7tgfjAAAWrAyWAAAB), which I need to convert to rest id.  Any idea on these ?

Comment: @Raj_003 thanks for providing me an example of StoreId. I was able to modify the script to convert StoreId to EntryId